# Best way to extract text from email using Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, power-automate

We have emails coming to our support inbox with this format:-

[image]

where the email will always contain 4 sections as marked in the above picture:-

1. First section >> starts with "Pick-up at:"
2. Second section >> starts with "Deliver to:"
3. Third section >> starts with "Miles:"
4. Forth section >> starts with "Notes:"

now i created an automated flow which trigger when an email is received >> but how i can extract the 4 sections content and store them inside 4 variables ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using "Compose" action to slice each bit of string you need, using fixed string lines as 'achors' to cut up the e-mail.

Something like this:
`slice(triggerBody()['text'],indexOf(triggerBody()['text'], 'Pick-up at:'),indexOf(triggerBody()['text'], 'Deliver to:'))`

Where `triggerBody()['text']` is you e-mail body.